# terminal-emulator with dynamic title from byobu/tmux session name

Tags: terminal, tmux, awesome-wm, byobu

At startup I use a little script that creates a number of byobu-sessions i.e. 'LOCAL','SSH','SSH2','INTERNAL','GUAKE','DEV'

I use a windows tiling manager (awesome wm) and most of the time I keep a terminal-emulator with a specific byobu-session on their designated desktop/tag.

At the moment I'm using xfce4-terminal-emulator, which has an option to use a dynamic title.
However, none of the solutions I've found seem to work in combination with byobu/tmux.
If I'm trying to find a terminal window in my window list, they all appear as `user@hostname(ip address)-byobu`

So, I would like to use a workflow where I can either set the window title from the terminal-emulator or it gets set when opening (or switching to) a byobu-session

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The terminal does not need any special "dynamic title" support – it literally just shows whatever text Byobu (or another application) is telling it to show. In this case, byobu always provides the same static text on startup. ($BYOBU_NO_TITLE would disable it entirely.)

More usefully, you can make tmux provide its own title (overriding the static one from Byobu) through a custom `~/.config/byobu/.tmux.conf`:

```
set -g set-titles on
set -g set-titles-string "#(whoami)@#H - byobu (#S)"
```

```
set -g set-titles on
set -g set-titles-string "#T (#h.#S.#I)"
```

The full syntax can be found in the *tmux(1)* manual page under "FORMATS" – in these examples, `#S` is the session name, `#W` and `#I` are the current window name & index, and so on.

Various programs running inside tmux/byobu will often provide their own terminal titles, so it's useful to include `#T` as well.

Comment: I noticed that all terminal-emulator sessions are sharing the title, a custom title per window could not be set. I ran this in one terminal and noticed in the windowlist that all my emulator had renamed their title to the tmux session name, exactly what I needed !!